# Application State works for some users but not others in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2, load-balancing

I have a very basic controller in my `ASP.NET Web API 2` where one HTTPGet method will set a DateTime in ApplicationState and return it, then the second HTTPGet method will **JUST** return that variable from app state, or return a new DateTime (0001-01-01T00:00:00) if the variable is null.

```
    [Route("appstate1")]
    [HttpGet]
    public DateTime appState1()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Application["dt"] = DateTime.Now;
        return (DateTime?)HttpContext.Current.Application["dt"] ?? new DateTime() ;
    }

    [Route("appstate2")]
    [HttpGet]
    public DateTime appState2()
    {
        return (DateTime?)HttpContext.Current.Application["dt"] ?? new DateTime();
    }
```

So with this being live

- I go to `https://example.com/api/appstate1` and set the time: (2017-05-31T09:14:19.4130002-07:00)
- Then I go to `https://example.com/api/appstate2`: (2017-05-31T09:14:19.4130002-07:00)
- Coworker A goes to `...appstate2`: (0001-01-01T00:00:00)
- Coworker B goes to `...appstate2`: (2017-05-31T09:14:19.4130002-07:00)

**UPDATE 1**

Immediately after reading my own post I remembered my API is load balanced between two servers...So this is less of a c# question and more of a server/IIS question I guess, but it still stands, because I don't know how to persist that data over the two servers.

Comment: So don't store the state in memory? Store it in a common location they can both access. That's what databases are for.

Comment: @mason The API is calling the db in other places, but some of the date doesn't need to be up-to-the-second data, and we would rather have it take up server memory than call the DB every time we need it. (which, from what I understand, is part of the goal of state data) I understand there are other ways to do it, but my question is how to make this way work.

Comment: I already answered how to make it work. Store it in a common location. Like a database. Cache the result if that ends up being a performance hit and you don't need the most up to date data, but don't try to pre-optimize.

Comment: Sticky session on the proxy could also do the trick I believe?